# Unable to print arabic character coming from request

Tags: database, spring-boot, encoding, arabic

I tried this and run as Java application:

```
`String data = "{\"eidaID\":\"حسنss\"}"; JSONObject obj = new 
JSONObject(data);`
      
System.out.println(obj.get("eidaID").toString());
O/p => حسنss
```

But, when it comes from the request in the spring boot application in the same manner,
`System.out.println("Key= :"+key+" with value= "+jsonObject.get(key).toString()+" is present");`

and run as spring boot app.
There, it comes as ?????

Can anyone please help here?

Comment: Do not use System.out. Prefer saving to file. If you want to use console/shell/terminal, check that it is UTF-8 compatible (and you have the correct fonts). You get here on stackoverflow a lot of question (and answer) on how to get a UTF-8 shell. But my take: save to file and read it from a file, and you gain productivity.

Comment: Will logger.info work  and saving into a file